# Jasper table remove line when blank

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to surpress printing an empty line in a jasper table if all the values are blank. Setting field(s) properties *Blank When Null* and *Remove Line When Blank* to true does not work for me, also the table has property *Remove Line When Blank* set to true.

Here is my reports definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8e8d2e06-defe-4759-b65d-0438240d3b54">
<style name="table">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<subDataset name="TabDS" uuid="a96780df-2bfa-488b-ae8f-02bca8eed34b">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 'HI' AS GREETING,TAX from list_vat --statement returns some rows and I would like to surpress printing lines with value = 0]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="GREETING" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TAX" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
</subDataset>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL -- DUMMY SQL STATEMENT JUST BE ABLE TO FILL THE TABLE]]>
</queryString>
<field name="DUMMY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9ae0840f-5051-447e-9072-7e5706b2dc02"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="TabDS" uuid="ef2dba26-e5bb-4ebf-885d-4c44bdc1306a">
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="c7995020-03e6-45bd-a287-889af0d312c2">
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="0b14de63-e049-48da-850b-a6d92f19a7d2"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{TAX}.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)==0 ?  null :$F{TAX})]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you omit the record in your SQL statement?

Comment: Hi Tom,thanks for your reply. For sure to modify the original SQL statement would be the simplest way how to accomplish this task:-). But unfortunately my real situation is not that easy, I need to get rid of a row in a table group, but I also have to use values from other columns in the row, so I cannot filter the whole row in an SQL statement.

Comment: I have not worked with Jasper tables, but can you use the Print When Expression?  If it makes it easier, you could also have a field in your SQL statement indicating whether to hide or show the row, and use that in the Print When Expression.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, but unfortunately PrintWhen doesnt work either:-). I can apply the condition to particular TextFields in a row, but even if the condition is applied to fields in all the columns, the blank row is printed anyway. Probably I'm missing something obvious, but seems to me that I'll have to try completely different approach and also get familiar with a crosstab component.